# R can't write to csv or RData file

Tags: r, csv, save

I'm trying to write the contents of a data frame to an RData file.

```
> save(collector2, file="collect2.RData")
Error in save(collector2, file = "collect2.RData") : 
  error writing to connection
```

As a 2nd option I tried using:

```
> write.csv(collector2, file="collect2.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

This executes and creates a file, but it is empty.

Here's the data frame I'm trying to write:

```
> head(collector2)
          adQuer1     rowid adQueravg
1 2485651|2284211 132000001 0.0000000
2      20888541|7 132000002 0.0152358
3      20888541|7 132987430 0.0152358
4      20888541|7 132595958 0.0152358
5      20888541|7 132621111 0.0152358
6      20888541|7 132464740 0.0152358
> str(collector2)
'data.frame':   17639105 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ adQuer1  : Factor w/ 7241603 levels "1000467|130715",..: 430440 229948 229948 229948 229948 229948 229948 229948 229948 229948 ...
 $ rowid    : num  1.32e+08 1.32e+08 1.33e+08 1.33e+08 1.33e+08 ...
 $ adQueravg: num  0 0.0152 0.0152 0.0152 0.0152 ...
```

Here is my system info:

```
> version
               _                            
platform       x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu     
arch           x86_64                       
os             linux-gnu                    
system         x86_64, linux-gnu            
status                                      
major          2                            
minor          15.0                         
year           2012                         
month          03                           
day            30                           
svn rev        58871                        
language       R                            
version.string R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
nickname
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Writing such long files will take some time. Are you waiting long enough?

Comment: @DWin: yes, I wait for the '>' on the next line to show up before doing anything.

Comment: Does it happen with shorter files?

Comment: Can you specify an absolute path in the file="....csv" operator/ check your current working directory with getwd() ? It'd be very unusual if you aren't getting any errors + it is not working. Also, have you tried write.table ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out it was a hard drive issue.  I was out of space and that was the message.

Answer (score 5):

Well the object you are trying to persist is not small.

In any event, I was not able to reproduce the error, but object size is the only possible source that i can see.

The middle column in your data frame, *rowid*, is type *double*, which are 64-bit integers, so that column is comprises the bulk of the object size. This suggests *persisting this column separately* from the other two--i.e., in two separate RData objects each persisted to its own file.

Second, perhaps try ***compression*** by passing in the appropriate arguments to ***save***

With a data frame having approx. 300K rows and 9 columns, i reduced the size of the RData object by a little *more than 1/2* using ***gzip*** compression.

a dataframe with 9 columns x approx. 300,000 rows

```
> dim(FG1)
[1] 282816      9

> dfile = "fg1.RData"
```

Creates an *RData* file 131 KB in size:

> save(FG1, file=dfile)

Creates an *RData* file 66 KB in size:

> save(FG1, file=dfile, compress=TRUE, compression_level=9)